# Android TabLayout height does not increase with font size

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Following is my code for `TabLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/city_grey"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/DashboardTabLayoutTextAppearance"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
    app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

And DashboardTabLayoutTextAppearance is

```
<style name="DashboardTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp40</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

As can be seen that `TabLayout` height has been set to `wrap_content` and tab text `textSize` has been sent to `40sp`.

So naturally the `TabLayout` height should increase as per the text height. But on some devices it's clipping the text off vertically.

Here is the result on a 7 inch tab
[image]

Whereas on a 5.5 inch phone it works perfectly fine
[image]

I tried playing around with the `layout_margin` and `padding` attributes but it didn't solve the issue.

**EDIT 1:** Added code to show I am initialising the `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(DashboardWeeklyFragment.newInstance(weeklyData), "Weekly");
    adapter.addFragment(DashboardMonthlyFragment.newInstance(monthlyData), "Monthly");
    adapter.addFragment(DashboardDailyFragment.newInstance(dailyData), "Daily");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: You need to give dynamic height because tablayout have their own dimension like toolbar, try to use dimen xml or programmatically.
Hope it will works!!!

Comment: giving fix height to you TabLayout may fix your problem

Comment: agree with set height programmatically to some percent of the whole screen height

Comment: But how will I come to know the amount of height that need to set based on the `fontSize`? Because it will be different on each screen.

Comment: If using wrap_content then it will take care automatically. Post your xml files to look into this more. Moreover how you are setting the textviews also matters

Comment: @Stallion I have set `TabLayout` height to `wrap_content` only. Added initialisation code, kindly check.

Comment: Did u find any solution to this ?

Comment: @AkshayShah no I didn't

Answer (score 0):

int height = 50;

make it dynamic like....
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height * this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

Comment: First of all, I am using `TabLayout` and not `TabHost` and second of all, I can't be sure 50 would be the perfect height in all scenarios.